# C3 Timeseries - show x ticks only every 15 minutes

Tags: javascript, charts, c3.js

I'm using C3 to generate an hour worth of measurments. It is updated every minute and oldest metric pops out of dataset and is replaced by new. So at any given time I have data for the last 60 minutes.

I would like to show the x value only on :00, :15, :30, :45 minutes. With count I can limit number of ticks to 4 but it starts from the chart creation time.

```
x: {
  type: 'timeseries',
  tick: {
    //fit: true,
    //count: 4,
    format: '%H:%M'
  }
}
```

This is not the full example but will do:
http://jsfiddle.net/ht2nrmg7/4/

Answer (score 2):

**First** we have to **show all ticks** - disable culling:

```
axis: {
    x: {
        tick: {
            culling: false,
```

Then we have to **detect and hide particular ticks** that you don't want to be displayed.

We take tick text, parse minutes from it and check if it snaps to 15-min steps. If not - we hide that element:

```
var chart = c3.generate({
    onrendered: function() {
    var cat = this
        .selectChart
        .select('.c3-axis-x')
        .selectAll('text')
        .each(function() {
            var text = d3.select(this).text();
            var textMin = text.match(/:(\d\d)/);
            if (!textMin) return;
            var m = parseInt(textMin[1], 10);
            if (m % 15 !== 0) {
                d3.select(this).style({ display: 'none'})
            }
        })
},
...
```

[See updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Dimmy/gLehxt8q/)

Answer (score 0):

You can set the exact values of the ticks that will be displayed in the chart, I'm relying on momentjs which has an awesome way to add/substract duration to a given date.

**c3 chart tick for x axis**

```
tick: {
  format: '%H:%M',
  rotate: -90,
  values: this.every(15, 'minutes')
}
```

**Date array generator based on momentJS**

```
every(increment, unit) {
  const startDate = ...; //<-- Your initial date
  const stopDate = ...;  //<-- Your stop date

  let ticks = [];
  let currentDate = startDate;

  while (currentDate <= stopDate) {
    ticks.push(currentDate)
    //Note the format part has to match you data.xFormat pattern
    currentDate = moment(currentDate).add(increment, unit).format('Y-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
  }

  return ticks;
}
```